# How to run this code faster? (it is currently taking 10min or so to run)

Tags: r, optimization

I have an R code but it is taking about 15 minutes to run, and as now I have to develop another one to basically do the same things but 10 times, I want to know if there is a way to make it run faster.

```
l = c()

LCI = 1000 - 3*4^(1/2)
LCS = 1000 + 3*4/4^(1/2)

for (i in 1:10000) {
  m = replicate(10000, (mean(rnorm(4, mean = 1001, sd = 4))))

  m[m < LCI | m > LCS]

  n = which(m %in% c(m[m < LCI | m > LCS]))

  l[i] = as.integer(n[1])
}

sum(l)

NMA = sum(l)/10000
show(NMA)
```

I have the idea that it takes so long because of the loop and of me replicating 10000 times a distribuition, but I don't know what could make it run faster. Can you help?

Comment: Can you explain what you try to achieve?

Comment: So, I needed to get 10000 numbers that are the mean of a certain distribution, then check the position of the 1st element that was out of the limits of control (LCI and LCS). I would do this 10000 times, then sum all the positions and see what is the mean value for this position.

Comment: So, is it correct that you need to get 10000 means of four random draws 10000 times?

Comment: Also, can you explain a bit more? These are random draws, so the order of the random draws is supposedly random itself. Why would you care about the first occurrence of an outlier?

Comment: It is correct. I mean, you are right in the second comment too, but I am just following the steps in order to complete my homework. I can complete it, but it is terrible to wait 15 minutes for the code to run.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but a lenghty comment: To figure out which part of the code needs to be rewritten, you would normally do something like the following:

```
#install.packages("profvis") # uncomment in case not installed
library(profvis)

profvis({

  for (i in 1:1000) { # changed number to 1000 for convenience
    m = replicate(1000, (mean(rnorm(4, mean = 1001, sd = 4))))

    #m[m < LCI | m > LCS] # This line doesn't do anything. 

    n = which(m %in% c(m[m < LCI | m > LCS]))

    l[i] = as.integer(n[1])
  }
  sum(l)

  NMA = sum(l)/1000
  show(NMA)
})
```

The output would be a visualization of which code takes up most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

One problematic aspect of the task is that you sample a random variable 10000 times just to make sure you don't miss the first time when it is outside the bounds. So if the 50th value is outside the bound, then you just keep replicating another 1950 times. I have adapted the code to avoid this (and improved the coding style).

On my computer, it takes about 9 seconds to complete.

```
set.seed(3234)

nsim <- 10000
result <- numeric(nsim)

LCI <- 1000 - 3 * 4^(1/2)
LCS <- 1000 + 3 * 4 / 4^(1/2)

for (i in 1:nsim) { # i <- 1
  good_luck <- TRUE
  j <- 0

  while (good_luck) {
    m <- mean(rnorm(4, mean = 1001, sd = 4))
    good_luck <- m >= LCI & m <= LCS
    j <- j + 1
  }

  result[i] <- j
}

mean(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if you set `x_bar <- (mean(rnorm(4, mean = 1001, sd = 4))))`

then according to the Central Limit Theorem x_bar is normally distributed with mean = 1001, sd = 4 / sqrt(4), where sqrt 4 = sqrt of the sample size.

So the term: `m = replicate(10000, (mean(rnorm(4, mean = 1001, sd = 4))))`

can be reduced to: m <- rnorm(10000, 1001, 2)